# What is the limit for no. of controls on an asp.net page & for the session variables?

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

is there any limit for adding controls on an asp page and how many session variables can be stored for a page and added for an application

Answer (score 0):

As am concerned the maximum number of controls allowed on a single form depends on the type of controls used and available system resources. However, there is a fixed limit of 254 control names per form.

But i would like you to suggest to keep the number of controls minimum.Because  Although you can have up to 254 control names in a form, a large number of controls in a form will severely degrade your program's performance. In some cases, you will experience out-of-memory error. To maximize the performance of your program, you should minimize the number of controls in each form.